# Retrieve the main key by using part of the sub value in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary which has subkeys and sub values. I want to print a list of the main keys that contain a certain value in the subkey. 
I hope the example makes it clear:

```
cssStyleDict= {'.c13':{'color':'#000',
               'font-family':'"Arial"',
               'font-weight':'700',
               'vertical-align':'baseline'},
               '.c6':{'font-weight':'700'}, 
               '.c7':{'color':'#000',
               'font-size':'11pt',
               'font-weight':'700',
               'text-decoration':'none'},
               '.c2':{'background-color':'#ff0'}}
```

I want to print a list of all keys that contain `{'font-weight':'700'}`.
I have tried this:

```
def getKeysByValue(dictOfElements, valueToFind):
    listOfKeys = list()
    listOfItems = dictOfElements.items()
    for item  in listOfItems:
        if item[1] == valueToFind:
            listOfKeys.append(item[0])
    return  listOfKeys

listOfKeys = getKeysByValue(cssStyleDict, {'font-weight':'700'} )
for key in listOfKeys:
    print(key)
```

But of course this only gives me an exact match. I've also tried using a regex expression, but to no avail. 
The output should be a list containing `.c13` `.c6` `.c7`

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
>>> [ i for i in cssStyleDict if cssStyleDict[i].get('font-weight') == '700' ]
['.c13', '.c6', '.c7']
```

Comment: Just a note, the `'701'` part isn't needed when retrieving the value of `font-weight`. The same can be achieved without it, as the default value of the `dict.get` method will be `None`, which won't equal `'700'`.

Comment: @Rúben didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To use the code that you’ve posted as a base for your answer, you only need to change the condition of the if-statement. Currently, you are checking for a perfect match because you have used “==“

However, Python comes with a great operator that does exactly what you need: “in”.

Thus, your new condition should be:

```
        If valueToFind in item[1]:
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Clear Approach using dictonary built-ins.

```
cssStyleDict= {'.c13':{'color':'#000',
               'font-family':'"Arial"',
               'font-weight':'700',
               'vertical-align':'baseline'},
               '.c6':{'font-weight':'700'}, 
               '.c7':{'color':'#000',
               'font-size':'11pt',
               'font-weight':'700',
               'text-decoration':'none'},
               '.c2':{'background-color':'#ff0'}}

for key, val in cssStyleDict.items():
  if(cssStyleDict[key].__contains__('font-weight')):
    if(cssStyleDict[key]['font-weight'] == '700'):
      print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by first checking each dict for that key, then comparing the value to the expected one.

```py
def getKeysByValue(dictOfElements, valueToFind):
    listOfKeys = list()
    listOfItems = dictOfElements.items()
    for k,v in listOfItems:
        try:
            if v[valueToFind[0]] == valueToFind[1]:
                listOfKeys.append(k)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return  listOfKeys

listOfKeys = getKeysByValue(cssStyleDict, ('font-weight', '700') )
for key in listOfKeys:
    print(key)
```